# Print only pages with certain phrase in a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, printing

It's possible print from a pdf file only the pages that contain a certain word?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Acrobat then no, but you can put together such functionality using the Acrobat SDK or the APDFL SDK.

It's possible to print only the pdf pages containing a certain word. PDWordFinder is part of Datalogics APDFL SDK.

You can use PDWordFinder to locate the specified word, and from there loop throughout the document building a print range of all the pages that contain the specified word.